# Infinite Product for Multiplicative Functions

Tags: reference-request, closed-form, infinite-product, multiplicative-function

> Do there exist closed form functional representations for the following products?:
> $$
> f(x,\alpha) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 + \alpha (n) \ x^n \right)
> $$
> Where $\alpha$ is some multiplicative function.

As examples:
For $\alpha(n) = 1$, this reduces to a form of the q-pochhammer symbol.
Expansion in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials may be obtained.

Any of the following insights would be appreciated:

- Are there any other simple cases for common multiplicative functions; such the Möbius function or any of the other classical functions?
- Do any references exist for this type of product in general?
- Are there any 'nice' series representations?
- What properties might such a closed form hold?

**Edit:**
Questions of covergence can be readily seen as this convergence is equivalent to the convergence of:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha(n) x^n
$$

Comment: you mean $\alpha(n) = -1$ (almost the Dedekind eta function). and $\prod_p 1+\alpha(p) x^p p^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\mu(n)|\alpha(n)x^{\sigma_p(n)} n^{-s} $ where $\sigma_p(n) = \sum_{p | n} p$ is an Euler product.

Comment: @user1952009 Both $\alpha(n) = -1,1$ have representations by the q-Pochhammer, but -1 is not multiplicative, so I did mean 1. For -1 it really is just the Euler Function. And I did notice the closeness to an Euler Product, but I was hoping for more potential for a simpler expression away from a product over primes.